# Low accuracy scores on portions of test dataset, high scores on full dataset

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of satellite spectral data collected in the four-year period 2018 - 2021 (separate observations for each year). I decided to split the dataset 7:2:1 to get the training, validation, and test subsets. I have trained a CNN (achieving good accuracy), validated it (also good accuracy), and finally tested it (good accuracy as well). I plan to use the model to classify upcoming datasets - the new ones will, of course, come from a single-year period (2022) thus I wanted to simulate how would it behave, and in order to do so, I  split my test dataset to single year observations (eg. 2018 only). When fed to the previously trained model it yielded a pretty poor accuracy score. It happened for all four years. model performance on single-year datasets was always significantly inferior to the full four-year dataset.

below is the example where i evaluate the model on two datasets and subsequently on the third dataset that consists of the previous two.

```py
#load trained model
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/GEEMAP/modelC2D")

#load datsets 1 and 2 and concatinate both to make dataset 3 
df1 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/GEEMAP/train_species/digest1.csv", index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/GEEMAP/train_species/digest2.csv", index_col=0)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True) # merged dataset consists of df1 and df2

#prepare dataset 1
df1x= df1.iloc[:,:-1] # separate values from classes
df1x=(df1x - df1x.mean())/df1x.std() #standardise
df1x= df1x.values.reshape(-1, 8, 4) #reshape to fit the model settings 
df1y= df1.iloc[:,-1] # separate classes


#prepare dataset 2
df2x= df2.iloc[:,:-1]
df2x=(df2x - df2x.mean())/df2x.std() 
df2x= df2x.values.reshape(-1, 8, 4)
df2y= df2.iloc[:,-1]

#prepare dataset 3
df3x= df3.iloc[:,:-1]
df3x=(df3x - df3x.mean())/df3x.std() 
df3x= df3x.values.reshape(-1, 8, 4)
df3y= df3.iloc[:,-1]


results1 = new_model.evaluate(df1x, df1y)
results2 = new_model.evaluate(df2x, df2y)
results3 = new_model.evaluate(df3x, df3y)
print("dataset1 test loss, test acc:", results1)
print("dataset2 test loss, test acc:", results2)
print("dataset3 test loss, test acc:", results3)
```

the output i get is:

```
dataset1 test loss, test acc: [1.0961114168167114, 0.7297353148460388]
dataset2 test loss, test acc: [0.9534237384796143, 0.7568098306655884]
dataset3 test loss, test acc: [0.6185511350631714, 0.8320053815841675]
```

How is this possible? Is there something profoundly basic about the workings of the cnn models that I am missing? It doesn't make much sense to me that the already trained model predicts with better accuracy when given just more work.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: I smell coding bug here, but if you don't share any code @desertnaut is correct.

Comment: @marco romelli, I've added the code example to my original question

Comment: One potential issue I see is with the normalization step. Try to use the mean and std computed on `df1` also for the normalization of `df2` and `df3` and see if results make more sense.

Comment: Yes, this approach solves the problem. Thank you! @marco romelli